# Array to hidden input field

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Is it possible to put an Array values to a hidden input field?

I am using ASP Classic code with javascript.

I have this asp code that puts every content of an Array to my hidden field.

```
Dim Data

    For Each Data in aRecords(14)
        Response.write "<INPUT type='hidden' name='hdn_field' value=""" & Data & """>" 
    Next
```

It appears in the view source like this:

```
<INPUT type='hidden' name='hdn_field' value="arrayvalue1">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='hdn_field' value="arrayvalue2">
```

But when i try to get the value of the "hdn_field" via javascript code. It doesn't work.

I call it by doing this (javascript):

```
testValue = document.frm_MainPage.hdn_field.value
```

I'm not sure if the mistake is in it's way of assigning it to hidden field or by the way i call it in javascript.

Please help.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are several hidden inputs with the same name, when you get the value of "hdn_field" you get all of those values in one go. To get only one value you need to give each hidden input a unique name.

Try something like this:

```
Dim length,i

length=ubound(aRecords)

for i=0 to length
    response.write "<INPUT type=""hidden"" name=""hdn_field" & i & """ value=""" & aRecords(i) & """>"
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating the value in the array into a delimited string or comma separated string and then assign in the hidden input field.When u get the value from hidden just split by comma to get the content of the array